# Having keystore error while migrating project from appybuilder to android studio

Tags: android-studio, keystore, app-inventor, android-keystore, android-app-signing

I made an app from appybuilder and published it on google play, now I want to release its update that I developed using android studio. Now, I am trying to sign my app with keystore that was generated by appybuilder, but I am getting the error-

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key 
keystore from store "E:\New folder\Work\android (2).keystore": Keystore was 
tampered with, or password was incorrect.
```

help me to fix this error.
I know I will not be able to publish its update without the sign of previous release.

when I tried to upload apk without app signing it gives me the error

```
Upload failed
You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable 
debugging before it can be published in Google Play. Learn more about 
debuggable APKs.
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your 
previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are 
signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: ****( previous SHA1 key)**** ]
and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have 
fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: 60:50:E5:C5:6F:DA:4C:13:4E:C4:99:65:E6:13:CA:08:37:BB:55:22 ]
```

Is there any way to change fingerprint to desired sha1 fingerprint?

Comment: Most likely that your key alias does not exist for your keystore file.

Comment: how can I solve this problem?

Comment: put some screen short or log in question to better understad

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: you can put your bulid.gradle file and i think keystore is same for previous and alias and password is match to no problem of upload apk

Comment: sorry I didn't understand what you are saying

Comment: follow the tips to [your question here](http://community.appybuilder.com/t/key-store-android-studio/1137?u=taifun)

Answer (score 0):

at last I found the solution. it was a error for alias, keystore password and key password. when I used the default values for them as

```
key store password - android

alias - androidkey

key password - android
```

Hope it will help someone. Thank you everyone.